# How to fix GASMO sync errors when dismissing meeting reminders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-workspace

I have a problem with Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook (GASMO) in that, when Outlook displays a meeting reminder for a meeting in my Google calendar, GASMO throws a sync error as soon as I dismiss it.

The `GoogleCalendarResponse.txt` file attached to the Sync Issue in Outlook contains the following

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "deleted",
    "message": "Resource has been deleted"
   }
  ],
  "code": 410,
  "message": "Resource has been deleted"
 }
}
```

however the meeting itself is still in my Google Calendar (and still in my Outlook calendar).

Selecting Re-sync with the "Overwrite" option re-synchronises my calendar with no issues reported.

Has anyone else seen this and fixed it (or does anyone know what to check)?